# Django foreign key doesn't work

Tags: sql, django, foreign-keys

(Running on google compute engine instance)

I've created the following model & database tables, the database tables were created before the module and were populated with data.

```
class MyCompany(models.Model):
    companyuniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'mycompany'

class MyUser(models.Model):
    UserUniqueID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'myuser'
```

I've created two simple views that do select all from the tables using django `company_list = MyCompany.objects.all()` same for the users all works fine!

**The Problem:**
when I try to enter to MyUser model the following `company = models.ForeignKey(MyCompany)`
calling to the service fails with the error: column `myuser.company_id does not exist`
MyUser database table has a column with reference to MyCompany.companyuniqueid column like so:
definition: `CompanyUniqueID BIGINT NULL`,
and reference:

```
CONSTRAINT user_company_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (CompanyUniqueID)
      REFERENCES MyCompany (CompanyUniqueID)
```

I read Django adds a default _id to primary keys but could not figure out how to remove it or point it to `companyuniqueid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all fields, you can use the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#db-column) parameter to specify the database column represented by the field:

```
company = models.ForeignKey(MMCompany, db_column='CompanyUniqueID')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use models.OneToOneField() is ForeignKey.

Comment: Please post some code. Oneliner answers are mostly not very helpful.